# Extracting particular node values from a list of nodes using HtmlAgilityPack in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xpath, web-crawler, html-agility-pack

I am crawling a page www.thenextweb.com

I want to extract all the post links, article content, article image etc.

I have written this code...

```
string url = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
        var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
        var document = webGet.Load(url);

        var infos = from info in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='article-listing']")
                    select new
                    {
                        Contr = info.InnerHtml
                    };

        lvLinks.DataSource = infos;
        lvLinks.DataBind();
```

This extracs all the required information from the page... and i have used this informatin in Home Page using listview control in asp.net page as

```
<li> <%# Eval("Contr") %> </li>
```

Now what i want is a way trhough which i can extract the nodes information as 
we have all the nodes present in **infos** containg link url, post image text etc.

I want a way so that i can store them as URL[0], PostContent[0], PostImage[0], Date[0] and  URL[1], PostContent[1] etc all these contains respected values which are being stored in these array strings....one by one each post...

Its like extracting information one by one from inner nodes in infos.

Please suggest a way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a class that parses the HTML and exposes those nodes as properties.

```
class ArticleInfo
{
    public ArticleInfo (string html) { ... }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public string PostContent { get; set; }
    public string PostImage { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }
}
```

You could then do something like this:

```
var infos = from info in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='article-listing']")
            select new ArticleInfo(info.InnerHtml);
```

Then if you have an array of these  `infoArray = infos.ToArray()'  you can do:

```
infoArray[0].URL
infoArray[0].PostDate
infoArray[1].PostContent

etc...
```

**Update**

Something like this:

```
class ArticleInfo
{
    private string html;

    public ArticleInfo (string html) 
    {
        this.html = html;
        URL = //code to extract and assign Url from html
        PostContent = //code to extract content from html
        PostImage = //code to extract Image from html
        PostDate = //code to extract date from html
    }

    public string URL { get; private set; }
    public string PostContent { get; private set; }
    public string PostImage { get; private set; }
    public DateTime PostDate { get; private set; }

    public string Contr { get { return html; } }
}
```

or maybe this:

```
class ArticleInfo
{
    private string html;

    public ArticleInfo (string html) 
    {
        this.html = html;
    }

    public string URL { get { return /*code to extract and return Url from html*/; } }
    public string PostContent { get { return /*code to extract and return Content from html*/; } }
    public string PostImage { get { return /*code to extract and return Image from html*/; } }
    public DateTime PostDate { get { return /*code to extract and return Date from html*/; } }

    public string Contr { get { return html; } }
}
```

Your link query then returns a sequence of `ArticleInfo` rather than the anonymous types.  This way you don't have to maintain separate arrays for each element of the post.  Each item in the array (or sequence) has properties to give you the associated element from that item.  Of course, this might not fit what you're trying to achieve.  I just thought it might be a bit cleaner.

Comment: hey i didn't got you clearly...can you provide me with full code to access the information as i stated in my question ?